# Empty file_get_contents('php://input')

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I tried to upload a JSON array to mySQL, but the  corresponding PHP file that should handle the POST isn't receiving the array

```
$jsonInput = file_get_contents('php://input'); 

// Convert it into a PHP 
object $newCoords = json_decode($jsonInput,true); 

console.log($jsonInput);
console.log($newCoords);
```

Although the sending script gave a console response text = 200 on the array sent to the receiving PHP-script the variables sent to the console in the receiving script do not show the contents (receiving the script in the code example). Any suggestions?

Comment: show you code ....

Comment: Sorry I included some code but I did something wrong in sending the question. code snippit: $jsonInput = file_get_contents('php://input');
 // Convert it into a PHP object
 $newCoords = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
 console.log($jsonInput);
 console.log($newCoords);

Comment: You can use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56714400/edit to edit/update the question